# Sync two or more SQL Server 2012 databases

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I am working on SQL Server 2012 and my requirement is to synchronize two or more databases that exist on different servers or locations.

I have tried this with 2008 by using synchronized option appear when we right click on database name.

But did not get any solution for SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Sounds like you want to set up [replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms151198.aspx)

Comment: What sync are you talking about? Data? Structures only? Both? What about frequency in which to sync? Real time? Batch? One shot? On deploy?

Comment: Thanks Alessandro to reply

I want to sync Data and it will be Real time

Comment: James S has given the answer.

Comment: Voting to close this old question as "too broad", and given just one answer below, this particular question is IMO not really resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this successfully using [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) on a database that needed to sync only specific data (ie. sync clients and orders between a web and a local database).

It is a bit painful to set up, but works brilliantly once in place.

That said, I wouldn't do it if you need to replicate the entire database.